# Nails in metal carpet trim won't hold

Tags: trim, carpet

There is an issue with my [carpet trim](https://www.lowes.com/pd/M-D-2-in-x-72-in-Gold-Carpet-Trim/3305910). Hammering the nails down isn't holding the piece anymore. The piece is 8 ft long and I am looking at a replacement trim at Lowe's.

I have two questions.

1. What do I do if the nails hammered in the trim won't hold? The nails are loose after I hammer them in. I am using specific nails and not ordinary ones.
2. How do I cut a new trim? I need a trim that is 8 ft long. Can I do multiple pieces instead of trying to find a single piece that is over 8 ft long?

Comment: "using specific nails and not ordinary ones" Care to share what these "specific" nails are? You can [edit] that into your question. When I go to the home center, I see boxes of "common" nails, and tons of boxes of "specific" types of nails, so that's not really helpful in identifying which ones.

Answer (score 5):

A new trim strip should be installed with the new nails at new locations--*not* aligned to the old ones.

Unless your subfloor is mushy, new nails in new locations should hold just fine. If they don't, get some brass screws with a slightly larger diameter than the nails. They'll probably do better. If you're on gypcrete or other soft material, plastic anchors for the screws might be required.

Cut your trim strip with a miter saw or hack saw. It's just aluminum. Hold it securely and use eye and ear protection. You can use multiple pieces if you align the ends carefully, but a single piece will look better and be less of a sock snagger.